# Prove that to fully connect $n$ nodes we need at least $n-1$ pairwise links

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have $n$ points/nodes, and we are given $m$ pairwise links/edges that we can use to connect arbitrary pairs of nodes.

Our goal is to arrange the edges in order to *fully connect* the nodes, that is, to have a configuration such that one can go from any node to any other node passing through the edges.

For example, for $n=4$ and $m=3$, denoting with $(ij)$ an edge between $i$-th and $j$-th node, such fully connected networks could be $(12)(23)(34)$, or $(12)(13)(14)$.

By trying this in a few cases, it seems clear that the smallest $m$ for which this is possible is $m=n-1$. What's a good way to prove that this is indeed the case?

Comment: see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)

Comment: I'm confused... @glS, aren't you a little overqualified for not knowing the answer to that question?

Comment: @user3733558 lol idk, am I? I find that even for dumb questions you can often get new interesting angles on how to approach the problem (e.g. in this case, I was wondering if this type of result fits into some more general results of graph theory, of which I know nothing)

Comment: @glS : my apologies then. There was this dissonance between the apparent very basic nature of the question, and the precise phrasing and framing giving the OP away as a consummate professional. I think I understand now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the *connected components* of a set of nodes and links (a graph) to be the maximal subsets of the nodes which are connected each other by paths. That is, two nodes are in the same component if they are joined by a path, and in different components otherwise.

- If there are no links, then no node can reach any other, so there are $n$ connected components.
- If a graph currently has $k$ connected components, and you add a single link to the graph, then the new graph has at least $k-1$ connected components. This is because, at best, the new link can join to components together, replacing those two with one and decreasing the over all number by $1$.

These two facts allow you to prove the following by induction: a graph with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges will have at least $n-m$ connected components. Therefore, if there are only $n-2$ links, there will be at least two connected components, so the graph is not connected.

Comment: ah, nice argument! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can easily prove it by induction.

Base case: $n=2$. You need $n-1=1$ edges. Graph connected.

Assume it is true that for $n$ nodes you need $n-1$ edges.

Now add a node, hence $n+1$ nodes. Just connect the last node to another node, and the number of edges become $n$.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced by this argument. Given $n$ fully connected nodes, you don't have the guarantee that any subset of $n-1$ nodes is fully connected, which is what you'd need to use the induction argument. You need to also prove that *there is* some subset of $n-1$ fully connected nodes. This is most likely the case, but would need to be also shown for this to be a complete proof

Comment: Base case: n=1. The graph is connected with 0 edges.
Inductive case: assume that for n=k nodes, your graph is connected with k-1 edges. If you add a node, it is sufficient to connect such node to one of the other nodes of the graph with an edge. So the proof is complete.

Answer (score 1):

First create a single link between two nodes. As all the nodes are to be connected, the network of links must be connected. Adding a new link to the existing network further connects at most $1$ new node, and we have $n-2$ nodes to add, hence $n-1$ links.

Comment: I don't quite follow this. This works as a construction of $n$ nodes fully connected by $n-1$ edges, but the question is to show that an arbitrary fully connected graph with $n$ nodes contains at least $n-1$ edges

Comment: My argument demonstrates that to have a connected graph on $n$ vertices you need at least $n-1$ edges, which implies that every connected graph on $n$ vertices has at least $n-1$ edges.

Comment: I don't follow the argument then. What do you mean exactly with "the network of links must be connected"? How do you define "connection" between edges?

Comment: Each new edge is added to a vertex that is already connected to $G$, and also to a new node.

Comment: not every fully connected graph is built by just connecting a new node to one of the previously connected ones. E.g. for (12)(34)(14), starting with (12), you cannot connect 3 to (12) (which is taken to mean to connect 3 to *one of* 1 and 2). You have to show that given a fully connected subset, there is *some* other vertex which connects to one of those in the fully connected subset you are building

Comment: But you can build 12,14,34. Every connected graph can be built like I explain.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $n \ge 2$. Let $(i, j)$ be an edge, with $i\not = j$. Simplify the graph by removing that edge and identifying the vertices $i$ and $j$. The new graph has one less egde and one less vertex. Hence the difference between the number of edges and the number of vertices remains the same. By induction, this difference must be $\ge -1$.

Comment: but if the nodes $i$ and $j$ were also connected to something else, doesn't this procedure remove more than one edge? For example consider three nodes with edges between all nodes. Identifying two nodes amounts to removing two edges but only one vertex

Comment: There are two ways to answer your question. The first way is to allow the graphs to have more than one edge between two nodes. Then you can remove only one edge. The other way is to remove as many edges as necessary. The difference "initial edges" - "initial nodes" is still larger than "final edges" - "final nodes", which is greater than $-1$ by the induction hypothesis, so the proof still works.